# My section appears higher when i inspect my webpage on google chrome?

Tags: html, css

My webbpage has different sections and when i want to add a background-image to my section it displays above my actual section. On the website itself my section appears normal but when i inspect my section google says that my section is above my actual section. Can someone explain me why this is happening or just give me a solution to this problem.  (hard to explain) if you need a picture i could send you it, just give your email.
[image]

> picture of me inspecting my .section-over in google Chrome the green
>   is the padding of my section, but is it normal that the
>   background-image only displays in the padding. However when i inspect
>   my navigation i only see the size of the navigation pointing upwards
>   to mark that my navigation is above my screen.

Here is a jsfiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/1y764zjs/1/

This is my basic setup, the problem is probably in this part of my coding but i am not sure, maybe it is a problem with my browser but i doubt it.

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000000;
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300px;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.clearfix {zoom: 1}
.clearfix:after {
    content: '.';
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}

section {
    padding-top: 80px;
}

.row-1 {
    max-width: 1140px;
}

/* ------------------------------------------------------- */
/* -- Header -- */
/* ------------------------------------------------------- */
```

This is my css for my header.[If i inspect my header google show me the size of my header with numbers with an arrow that points upwards---above the section. That's why i suspect that all my sections are above where they are supposed to be.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJVhU.png)

```
.logo {
    height: 50px;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    float: left;
}



.navi {
    float: right;
    font-size: 125%;
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.98);
    z-index: 9999;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.98);
}

.navi li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-bottom: -30px;
    float: right;
}

.navi li a {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.navi li a:link,
.navi li a:visited {
    padding: 23px 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 90%;
    border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
    transition: border-bottom 0s;
}

.navi li a:hover,
.navi li a:active {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #000000;
}

.waar {
    margin-right: 150px;
}


/* ------------------------------------------------------- */
/* -- Over -- */
/* ------------------------------------------------------- */
```

This is my code for my section where i want to put my background.

```
.over {
    background-image: url(img/zorg.jpg);
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(181, 181, 181, 0.72), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)), url(img/zorg.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle with the HTML included so we can see the whole problem?

Comment: The picture is of the inspected header, not the section.